# Parse json into array in bash

Tags: json, linux, bash, awk, sed

```
{
    "db_status": {
        "sysa": {
            "taskname": "AB",
            "state": "Running",
            "status": "System ATTENTION",
            "updated": "0727",
            "version": "5"
        },

        "sysb": {
            "taskname": "null",
            "state": "Standby",
            "status": "System OK",
            "updated": "0727",
            "version": "6"
        }
    }
}
```

CURL command returns json object. Trying to get both state variables in an array i.e. running and standby. So far i have tried

```
curl -s http://localhost:9099/api | grep state | sed 's/"//g' | awk -F  ": " '/state/ {print $2}' | tr '\n' ' ' |  sed s'/..$//'
```

Comment: dont have package jq or python installed in the server.

Comment: You can edit the detail in the question no need to  put that in comment and also your code is not indented properly please indent that properly

Answer (score 2):

FYI you don't need a pipeline of 20 different commands when you're using awk. The command line you provided can be written as just one command:

```
awk -F'"' '$2=="state"{printf "%s%s", (++c>1?", ":""),$4}'
```

but all you really need is:

```
awk -F'"' '$2=="state"{print $4}'
```

and to save the output in a shell array (assuming your json is really always formatted as you show in your question) would be:

```
$ arr=( $(cat file | awk -F'"' '$2=="state"{print $4}') )
$ echo "${arr[0]}"
Running
$ echo "${arr[1]}"
Standby
```

Replace `cat file` with your `curl` command.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)

```
$ curl -s http://localhost:9099/api | jq '.db_status.sysa.state, .db_status.sysb.state'
"Running"
"Standby"
```

Or if you want all the entries no matter how many

```
$ curl -s http://localhost:9099/api | jq '.db_status[].state'
"Running"
"Standby"
```

Alternatively, if you don't have `jq` (or just looking for ways of feeling pain) you can parse most json in bash using  [`ticktick`](https://github.com/kristopolous/TickTick) -- which is written in 250 lines of bash